# How to model a multiple choice possibility in a ontology?

Tags: semantic-web, owl, protege

I'm using protege 5 and trying to convert a questionnaire to an ontology. And I cant figure out how to model a multiple choice answer. I have a class (Class1) which has elements and for each element a person can select one or more of allowed values.  Eg:
ElementOne : "someStringValue1", "someStringValue2", "someStringValue3", someStringValue4" .
And the user can pick "someStringValue1" and "someStringValue2".

Any ideas how to model this in protege and owl?

Comment: Are the choices supposed to be individuals or literals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use enumerated classes to model a fixed set of choices.  E.g., you can say things like

Question2Answers ≡ {"choice a", "choice b", "choice c", "none of the above"}
        question2 ⊑ ∀ hasAnswer.Question2Answers

Here's an ontology you can download and see examples. In it, I've declared two question individuals, and three answer individuals. I've defined two properties *hasObjectAnswer* and *hasDataAnswer*, so you can either use individuals or datatyped literals as answers.  I've said that the possible answers for question1 are answerA, answerB, and answerC, by asserting that

question1 ⊑ ∀ hasObjectAnswer.{answerA, answerB, answerC}

[image: question1 axiom]

I've said that the possible answers for question2 are "answer one", "answer two", "answer three", and "none of the above" by using the axiom:

question2 ⊑ ∀ hasDataAnswer.{"answer one", …, "none of the above"}

[image: question2 axiom]

```
@prefix :      <urn:ex:> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

:answerB  a     owl:Thing , owl:NamedIndividual .

:question2  a   owl:Thing , owl:NamedIndividual ;
        a       [ a                  owl:Restriction ;
                  owl:allValuesFrom  [ a          rdfs:Datatype ;
                                       owl:oneOf  ("answer one" "answer two" "answer three" "none of the above")
                                     ] ;
                  owl:onProperty     :hasDataAnswer
                ] .

:answerA  a     owl:Thing , owl:NamedIndividual .

:question1  a   owl:Thing , owl:NamedIndividual ;
        a       [ a                  owl:Restriction ;
                  owl:allValuesFrom  [ a          owl:Class ;
                                       owl:oneOf  ( :answerC :answerB :answerA )
                                     ] ;
                  owl:onProperty     :hasObjectAnswer
                ] .

:hasObjectAnswer  a  owl:ObjectProperty .

:hasDataAnswer  a  owl:DatatypeProperty .

:answerC  a     owl:Thing , owl:NamedIndividual .
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One more question though: If I have a class eg. Building and i want to say Builiding hasElements Elements (class), and i want to define multichoice for each Element eg Element1, Element2, Element 3, and for the building each element must be defined. And each element can have multichoice literals eg: Element1 can have values: "value1", "value2", "value3" how do i model that? Do I do it the same way by creating indivuduals with restrection like in the example above?